# Automate data pull from App Annie API issue

Tags: python, json, appannie

I am needing to automate a daily pull of app Annie data reviews and land them in S3. With the below I am trying to see if I can just pull one days worth of data but am getting an error 'TypeError: expected string or buffer'. I am new to python, can someone explain what I am doing wrong or another way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://api.appannie.com/v1.2/apps/ios/app/331177714/reviews?       
start_date=2016-1-01&end_date=2016-6-26&countries=US'
key = 'Authorization: bearer 585e46.....'

response = requests.get(url, 
                        headers = {'Authorization':'bearer 585e46.....'})   

data = json.loads(response.json())
```

Comment: What happens if you just call `response.json()`? Have you tested for yourself that the response is formatted as json?

Comment: @cmaher that worked. Thank you as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.json` method you're using comes from requests object and it already converts string to proper json. So you can do two things

1. Convert to json with requests object method:
   `data = response.json()`
2. Get text from your response and turn into json with Python json lib:
   `data = json.loads(response.text)`

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it the error message I was encountering.

Comment: which option have you chosen? ;)

Comment: data = response.json() . My next item to tackle is how to land this data into an S3 bucket. :)

Comment: drop my an URL when you'll write more details in new post ;)